# Locution latine "Alma mater": Est-elle courante ?

Tags: locutions, latin

- Peut-on employer alma mater en parlant de l'université dans laquelle une personne a étudié ? Wiki en parle pour la Suisse, la Belgique, le Canada, les pays anglophones mais elle n'en dit rien pour la France.
- Son emploi métaphorique (en parlant de la nature) est-elle aussi courante ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'éviterais de l'employer.

Le risque est très grand de ne pas être compris, que ce soit au sens propre ou au sens figuré.

Comment: Entre-soi si, (et je crois comprendre que Dimitris est compris dans le *soi*), il sera compris comme il le faut. Maintenant... les universitaires français voyagent beaucoup alors... passé par Cambridge ? Bologne ? Hmmm... ça va finir par... se *fritter*! Et en ce sens... oui effectivement... il risque d'être mal compris. (Note que jdisçajdisrien moi je sors de l'École.)

Answer (score 1):

D'après le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/alma_mater) il n'y a pas de problème, ce terme s'utilise en français, même s'il est encore rare.

Le sens "mère nourricière" est un sens par extension qui est aussi utilisé.

À la section des locutions latines du Petit Larousse de 1959 on trouve ce qui suit.

> Alma mater *ou* Alma parens : expressions souvent employées par les poètes latins pour désigner la patrie et quelques fois par les écrivains de nos jours pour désigner l'université.

L'usage courant, s'il existe, date donc d'après 1959 ; je pense qu'il ne doit pas être très courant mais tout indique que le terme est utilisable.